# Entity Framwork 6 converting NVARCHAR TO INT MAX

Tags: entity-framework

I have a NVARCHAR column in my database.  I want to get the maximum numeric value and increment it by one.  If I was running direct sql, I'd use:

```
select max(cast(identifier as int)) + 1 from item where ISNUMERIC(identifier) = 1
```

How would I do this in Entity Framework?